# how to Use Private framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

i need to use a framework in apple private framework in xcode 8.0 .
this version of xcode doesnt have any private framework file and deleted all file in "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks" folder .

header framework Link : [PrivateFramework](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/AppPredictionInternal.framework)

this framework that i use published for ios 9.0 and later , 
so not use in xcode 7.0

how can i use this framework to my project?

Comment: Check `Sample usage` here: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Comment: @vitormm tnks , work it :)